# Pass a function into an array and then call it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a function into an array and then call it later on.

```
// So add it here
var list = [{ Name: "Name1", Name2: "Name", Function: test() }]

// Then call it later which will run the function
list.Function;

function test(){
    var test = "test";
    console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: You are storing the result of the function `test` into the array.  You aren't storing the function itself.  And that function returns `undefined` anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to call the function when you put it in the list, which is what you are doing when you add `test()` to the array. This will call the function when you make the list and add the result to the list. Also, to call it when you reference it you need to include the index:

```js
function test(){
    var test = "test";
    console.log(test);
}
// So add it here
var list = [{ Name: "Name1", Name2: "Name", Function: test }] // just add a reference to test no `()`

// Then call it later which will run the function
list[0].Function();  // list is an array so you need to reference the first item
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from Mark Meyer. What I would like to add is that what makes this possible is in Javascript functions are first class members. There are not different from any other Object.

Therefore, we can even assign properties to a function like this:

```js
function foo () {}

foo.bar =  5;

console.log(foo.bar);
```

This also implies that we can store them in an Array like this:

```js
function foo () {console.log('test')};

let arr = [foo];   //stores a reference of the function foo

arr[0]()  // access the reference and execute it
```

We can store the reference (pointer to place in memory) in an Array so we then can later on call the function using the `()` operator

Hopefully this will clarify it even more ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// First Method/Function
function messageOne()
{
  console.log("Inside First Method !")
}
// Second Method/Function
function messageTwo()
{
  console.log("Inside Second Method !")
}

// A List which stores methods reference
var list = {"one":messageOne,"two":messageTwo}

// Call Each methods/Function from list
list["one"]()
list["two"]()
```